# How to create a webdriver function which passes parameters for a test script?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a function for a login test script which passes parameters such as Username and Password. I am new to this please do elaborate. Here's the code I've written--

```
public void portalLogin(String Username, String Password){

driver.get(URL);
driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(Username);
driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(Password);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.submitBtn")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

I just want to call this weird of a function to another test class, so that I don't have to write this over and over again. Please help!

Comment: Set the implicit timeout once and at the beginning. Also, are you trying to use the Page Object pattern?

Comment: @Arran I think I'm trying to use Page Object pattern. Haven't done this b4. Can you please turn my code to that pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that you were trying to use the page object pattern.  Here's what I think you are looking for:

```
public class LogonPage {
@FindBy(id="UserName")
public WebElement userNameField;
@FindBy(id = "Password")
public WebElement passwordField;
@FindBy(css = "input.submitBtn")
public WebElement submitButton;

public LogonPage(WebDriver driver){
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
public void portalLogin(String username, String password){ //Only call this when you are already on the logon page
        userNameField.clear();
        userNameField.sendKeys(username);
        passwordField.clear();
        passwordField.sendKeys(password);
        submitButton.click();
        //Waiting should also be done after the function
}
```

}

You will then have to do this in your main code:

```
LogonPage page = new LogonPage(driver);
page.doLogin(username, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the time out and navigate to the URL first. Open the login page in application.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
driver.get(URL);

    public void doLogin(String Username, String Password)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(Username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(Password);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.submitBtn")).click();
    }
```

Let me know if you require more help...

Comment: @Smit getting an error says "Component returned failure code: 0X904b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URl)"

Comment: @Ash I am not a person who gave answer. It was @ Vinay, I just formatted his code snippet. You should address to him. The error you are mentioned its about `URL`. Can you show us the `URL` string in your code?

Comment: @Smit thanks for the heads up. I put a semicolon mistakenly after http. Anyway, so the code runs but I'm getting an NullPointerException.

Comment: @Vinay thanks dude. The code ran but getting NullPointerException.

Comment: @Ash You should add that `NPE` stacktrace to your post and also point us to that line from where its throwing `NPE`. Anyhow `NPE` get thrown when defined instance is `null` or not initialized.

Comment: @Smit my class name to the test was test...so I initiated this to different class like below--
test t = new test()
//then wrote all the junit annotation and stuff
t.doLogin("myusername", "mypassword")

Comment: @Ash this is not the thing causing `NPE`. its a `URI` thing I guess as you mentioned earlier. Add the `stackstrace` to your post and point the line. without that its not possible to help you.

Comment: @Smit my class name to the test was test...so I initiated this to different class like below--
test t = new test()

(then wrote all the junit annotation and stuff)
Before
public void setUp(){
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(my url)
}
Test
public void newTest(){
t.doLogin("myusername", "mypassword")}

thats giving me NPE...on the line where I did the t.doLogin.....

Comment: @Ash very appreciative if you can pass on the stack trace. Without that very difficult to pin point actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a JUnit Parameterized test.  I think this is what you are asking for.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class DataProviderTest extends WebDriverUtils {

    private static String testName, searchString, ddMatch;

    public DataProviderTest( String tName, String sString, String dMatch ) {
        testName = tName;
        searchString = sString;
        ddMatch = dMatch;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {   
        System.out.println("setUp");
    }

    @Parameters(name = "{0}: {1}: {2}")
    public static List<String[]> loadParams() {
        File tFile = loadGradleResource( System.getProperty("user.dir") + separator +  "build" +
                separator + "resources" + separator +  "test" + separator + "testdata2.csv" );
        List<String[]> rows = null;
        if ( tFile.exists() ) {
            CSVReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new CSVReader( new FileReader( tFile ), ',' );
                rows = reader.readAll();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
        //String[][] csvMatrix = rows.toArray(new String[rows.size()][]);
        System.out.println("Finished loadParams()");
        return rows;
    }  

    @Test
    public void testParams() {
        System.out.println("Param '{}' being run...", testName );
        System.out.println("Search string: " + searchString );
        System.out.println("ddMatch: " + ddMatch );
        System.out.println("Test '{}' is done.", testName );
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        System.out.println("Finished cleanUp");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static WebDriver LoginPage(String URL, CharSequence UName, CharSequence Pwd) throws Exception 
        {
          driver.get(URL);
          driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
          driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(UName);
          driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
          driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(Pwd);

          // [click on link or button after which popup window will appear. ] 
         driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    //   System.out.println("URL of the page before - switchingTo: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());  
         Thread.sleep(2000);

          //Switch to newly opened window and get the page titele    
               for(String CurrentWindowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
                   {   driver.switchTo().window(CurrentWindowHandle);     
                   }  

            System.out.println("URL of the page after - switchingTo: " + driver.getCurrentUrl()); 
             Thread.sleep(3000);
             return driver;
        }
```

Then in the Driver script it can be called as 
LoginPage(vURL,vUserName,vPassword);